# Cleaning up added records to the database after UI acceptance tests

Tags: database, selenium, ui-automation, specflow, acceptance-testing

I know there have been a lot of questions asked about cleaning up data once a test is complete.  A lot of them have said to mock the database to avoid using the real database then just clean that up once the test is done.  I am not sure if that will work with what I am doing so here it goes.

I am using SpecFlow for .net, using Selenium for the WebUI and NUnit for the test runner.

The application itself is a large muli-page web app.

The SpecFlow features are separated by page functionality and most if not all pages have a table displaying the created records.  Ex. I create a new category and the page displays the added category in the table.  To be able to run these tests over and over, I need to remove all added records that the tests created from the database so those same categories can be recreated when the tests get reran.

We have a skeleton  setup to run after each feature that will pass in a stored procedure to delete those added records from the database.  There has been a lot of push back on that idea because of the risk of deleting records for a different test client in the test environment.

So, my question is, what is the best practice for cleaning up the database?

Comment: Sorry, Are you using a database that shares live production client data with test data?

Comment: Okay, I am sorry, no, all the environments before we get to production do not have production client data.   However, they do want to run these tests in prod, in which case, the test client would be sharing the database.  We aren't at that level yet so that is really yet to be determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to delete the test data both before and after the test runs. This way the data will be cleaned up even if a test aborted half way through and doesn't clean up afterwards.

In specflow this can be achieved by using before scenario/after scenario/before feature/after feature hooks.

If possible the ideal solution is to have a new database for each test then you can just delete the entire database. This will allow the tests to be run in parallel.

If you can't do that then you want some way to identify the test data uniquely for each test.

It's worrying that your question implies test and live data in the same database

Comment: Thank you!  I currently do have it setup to run both before the feature and after the feature.  I am just trying to find the best solution to clear the created data from the tables that were affected during the test. Whether that is creating a back up then restoring, running a stored procedure to delete those rows specific to the test client, or using a soft delete.  Sorry for the misunderstanding. All of the clients are test clients and it is all test data that is being created.